# Using a 555 IC to trigger an ESP8266

Tags: sensor, esp8266

I have a non-contact AC voltage detector with a 555 IC which I want to trigger an ESP8266 module to send a notification when power is restored after an outage. Since the notification only needs to be sent once, how would one prevent the 555 from triggering the 8266 every time it fires?

Comment: What does the output of the 555 look like?  Pulse per pulse of AC?  Can you make it a retriggerable oneshot instead?

Comment: Hi ChuckE, welcome to SE.EE. You need to add a lot more detail to this question. Show what you've designed so far, ideally a schematic. Explain why you expect the 555 to fire multiple times. What does the 555 do in the first place? How is the ESP powered? As much detail as you can.

Comment: @Aaron  Being outside the electronics world, I don't know how to answer your questions but you've sent me some directions to study.  That said, wouldn't a non-retriggerable one shot be more appropriate?

Comment: @ChuckE no. Why even use a separate IC at all? The ESP8266 is a full microcontroller and can do all that a 555 could do, by itself, and much more. And that at negligible extra power consumption (very much opposed to the classical NE555, which eats *a lot* of power).

Comment: @ Marcus Müller I use the detector with a low-power FM transmitter to signal the restoration of AC.  A mic on the transmitter sends the detector buzzer to a battery-powered radio in the house.  I want the ESP8266 to streamline the notification process and expand the number of recipients.
The ESP8266 w/out the IC would certainly simplify things.  The buzzer could be eliminated to lighten the load even more.
I’m a retired film/video lighting tech unversed in electronics.  I’ll do more research.  Tips and direction will be much appreciated.